# When using wildcard, only one file is ran in rails runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails runner, and I'd like to run multiple scripts in a folder.

Here is what my files structure looks like...

```
$ ls db/test/

de_test.rb
fr_test.rb
ja_test.rb
....
```

de_test.rb

```
puts "DE"
```

fr_test.rb

```
puts "FR"
```

ja_test.rb

```
puts "JA"
```

Now if I run:

```
$ bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/de_test.rb
DE
$ bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/fr_test.rb
FR
$ bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/ja_test.rb
JA
$ bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/*test.rb
DE
```

Why doesn't `db/test/*test.rb` run all the files? And what can I do to fix this.

This is on RHEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash globs are just shorthand for writing multiple filename arguments at a time:

This:

```
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/*test.rb
```

will be entirely identical to if you had written:

```
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/de_test.rb db/test/fr_test.rb db/test/ja_test.rb
```

The documentation is lacking, but most likely this will just run `de_test.rb` with the other files as additional command line parameter. This is why you only see `DE`.

What you wanted to do was instead to run one command per file, i.e.:

```
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/de_test.rb
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/fr_test.rb
bundle exec script/rails runner -e production db/test/ja_test.rb
```

You can do this with a for loop:

```
for file in db/test/*test.rb;
do
    bundle exec script/rails runner -e production "$file";
done
```

(you can put it all on one line if you prefer)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze why it happens. I removed everything from `rails/runner` task. By saying everything i mean things, which not related to your question. You can check this code in your computer.

```
require 'optparse'
code_or_file = nil

puts ARGV
puts code_or_file

if ARGV.first.nil?
  ARGV.push "-h"
end

ARGV.clone.options do |opts|
  opts.order! { |o| code_or_file ||= o } rescue retry
end

puts code_or_file
```

So `puts ARGV` will show every file that satisfies to your `db/test/*test.rb`.

Line `puts code_or_file` will show empty line (it's normal because variable has `nil` value)

Last line `puts code_or_file` will print the **first** file in folder by `lexicographical order`.

So why it happens? Because of:

```
opts.order! { |o| code_or_file ||= o } rescue retry
```

Simply it takes first item in array(list of files). My suggestion is rewrite/patch `rails/runner` task to solve your problem. Another way will be write  `shell` script as offered by @that_other_guy.

[rails/runner link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation